# Print value of MediaDrmCallback functions

Tags: android, drm, exoplayer2.x

I am currently working on DRM with ExoPlayer and I am trying to figure out what the MediaDrmCallback's functions return i.e. executeProvisionRequest and executeKeyRequest as ByteArray. I read the Developer page for MediaDrm but it says the server returns License which I would like to print but only problem is it's in ByteArray

I tried using UTF-8 encoding and ASCII encoding but both of them print some unknown characters.

```
override fun executeProvisionRequest(uuid: UUID?, request: ExoMediaDrm.ProvisionRequest?): ByteArray {
    val url = request?.defaultUrl + "&signedRequest=" + String(request!!.data)
    return executePost(url, null, null)
}

override fun executeKeyRequest(uuid: UUID?, request: ExoMediaDrm.KeyRequest?): ByteArray {
    val requestProperties = HashMap<String, String>()
    requestProperties["X-AxDRM-Message"] = mAxDrmMessage
    return executePost(mLicenseServer, request!!.data, requestProperties)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you would like to print out the license itself, i.e. the decryption key, then you won't be able to as the DRM systems also encrypt the key and only the DRM client itself is configured to decrypt it. This decryption is not done in any open or observable way.

One of the primary purposes of DRM systems like Widevine, PlayReady etc is to securely transfer the key between the license server and the client/player.